# 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' does not contain a definition for 'setRow' WP 8 project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make a cryptogram puzzle for Windows 8 Phone.
.net framework is 4.5

I am encountering this following error:  **'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' does not contain a definition for 'setRow'** at Grid.setRow(txt, x); I want to create textboxes dynamically, without using XAML...

To the best of my knowledge, Windows.Controls.Grid has a static method Grid.setRow(UIelement, int)..

Here is **MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using System.IO;

namespace CryptogramPuzzle
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    List<string> quotes;
    List<TextBox> tb;
    int length = 0;
    int width;
    int height;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random r = new Random();
        string encodedStr;

        InitializeComponent();

        getQuotes();
        int rInt = r.Next(0, quotes.Count()); //generates random index for a quote selection
        encodedStr = Encryption.encode(quotes[rInt]);
        length = encodedStr.Length;
        createTxtBox(0, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads quotes from the text file
    /// </summary>
    public void getQuotes()
    {
        quotes = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            StreamResourceInfo sInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/CryptogramPuzzle;component/Resources/Puzzles.txt", UriKind.Relative));
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sInfo.Stream);//feeds the reader with the stream
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                quotes.Add(line);
            }
            sr.Close();
            // System.Console.WriteLine(quotes[0]);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }

    public void createTxtBox(int x, int y)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        RowDefinition newRow = new RowDefinition();
        newRow.Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
        ContentPanel.RowDefinitions.Add(newRow);
        txt.MinHeight = 10;
        txt.MinHeight = 10;
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(txt);
        Grid.setRow(txt, x);

    }


}
 }
```

Here is my **MainPage.xaml**:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="CryptogramPuzzle.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- LOCALIZATION NOTE:
        To localize the displayed strings copy their values to appropriately named
        keys in the app's neutral language resource file (AppResources.resx) then
        replace the hard-coded text value between the attributes' quotation marks
        with the binding clause whose path points to that string name.

        For example:

            Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"

        This binding points to the template's string resource named "ApplicationTitle".

        Adding supported languages in the Project Properties tab will create a
        new resx file per language that can carry the translated values of your
        UI strings. The binding in these examples will cause the value of the
        attributes to be drawn from the .resx file that matches the
        CurrentUICulture of the app at run time.
     -->

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

    </Grid>

    <!--Uncomment to see an alignment grid to help ensure your controls are
        aligned on common boundaries.  The image has a top margin of -32px to
        account for the System Tray. Set this to 0 (or remove the margin altogether)
        if the System Tray is hidden.

        Before shipping remove this XAML and the image itself.-->
    <!--<Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="480" Margin="0,-32,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
</Grid>
```

Please help me to fix this error, getting pretty desperate!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a standard framework method, I'm pretty sure standard Pascal-casing rules ([the guidelines that MS follows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) at least) dictate it would be called `SetRow` and not `setRow`.

And [indeed it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setrow.aspx).